# My Touran VW 2011 Key Fob has gone crazy

Tags: vw, key, fob

My key fob seems to have gone crazy.

For the last few months, it would open and close the doors on the Touran without ever being pressed.

It seems to do this every time I walk up to the car or bump the fob chain or even start the car.  When I start the car, the side door will open or the back trunk tailgate will open.

It's very annoying and potentially dangerous.  More than once, we've come out of a store or restaurant and the doors are open.

I have changed the battery and I don't think it's from accidentally hitting the keys as it happens when it's in my pocket.

Any thoughts? Do I need to get a new one or call the dealership?

Comment: Welcome to the site ... when you say open, do you mean actually pop open? Or just unlock? And are you sure it's the fob doing it?

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 things you can look at:

- **The KeyFOB**: are the buttons of your FOB sticking? This could cause the FOB to keep sending unlock signals. To rule this out, remove the battery of your KeyFOB. If the problem continues, the issue is not with the KeyFOB.
- **The car's unlock switches**: Do these stick after you use them? One way to rule them out is to remove the door panel and disconnect them. If the problem continues, it wasn't them.

Try the above and edit your post with your results.

Comment: 'fob' is not an acronym, no need to capitalize it.

Comment: @Hobbes Yes it is. "Feature Obviously Broken." Duh.